# tsc not recognized after global install inside Windows Sandbox

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, npm, virtual-machine, windows-sandbox

I installed globally as told here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling

```
npm install -g typescript
```

both inside vscode and outside, though it installed, tsc --version doesn't work : tsc is not recognized.

I have no problem outside Windows Sandbox https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview

So is there a fix in this context ?

Comment: What is output of: `npm config get prefix` and `npm ls -g --depth 0`? Is the "prefix" directory contained in PATH environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the typescript with this command

```
npm install typescript@latest -g
```

then tsc will be recognized

```
tsc --init
```

source : https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-tsc-command-not-found